# Accessing JSON request parameters in Sails

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

In my controllers and other areas where there's a `req` object, I can access request parameters using `req.params('username')`. This is fine for normally POSTed data, but I want my API to accept a JSON object in the request body and convert it to parameters that I can still access with `req.params()`.

So for example, if I send this as the POST request body to my controller action:

```
{'username': 'Chris', 'password': 'mypass'}
```

I want to be able to get the username and password using `req.params('username')` and `req.param('password')`.

At the moment the only thing that works is sending the data like this:

```
username=Chris&password=mypass
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you want the singular params, req.param('username')

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I just have to send the request body as `application/json` rather than the default.

Comment: Can you link a source about that? I'm interested, didn't know that was even possible.

Comment: I don't have a source sorry, the docs don't seem to mention it anywhere. On a whim I decided to try it as I've seen the same thing in other frameworks and it worked.

Comment: This is mentioned, albeit somewhat indirectly, in the [docs for `bodyParser.json()`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser#bodyparser-json-options-) with the `type` option — "*The `type` argument is passed directly to the [type-is](https://www.npmjs.org/package/type-is#readme) library. This can be an extension name (like `json`), a mime type (like `application/json`), or a mime time with a wildcard (like `*/json`).*" The `type-is` module mentioned is a `Content-Type` tester.

Answer (score 1):

req.query is working for me when I send a get request with parameters as

/request?param1=a&param2=b

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from `req.body`. See http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/req/req.body.html